# Delphi sort by sum of three fields - delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-access

I have a database (*.mdb), scheme of connection, that I use in my program:

```
TADOConnection -> TADOTable
```

DB has a table named Table1, which is connected by ADOTable. In Table1 there are fields A, B, C - floating point values. I need to sort the table by sums of these numbers.

For example:

```
Name   A   B   C
------ --- --- ---
John   1   2   5
Nick   1   5   3
Qwert  1   5   2
Yuiop  2   3   1
```

I need to sort them, so the name, which A+B+C is bigger, would be first.
Sorted variant:

```
Name   A   B   C
------ --- --- ---
Nick   1   5   3
John   1   2   5
Qwert  1   5   2
Yuiop  2   3   1
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this, I understood what to do: I need a calculated field in the table, which is equal to A+B+C, and I must sort the table using it.

Comment: to have a calculated field is a nice idea

Answer (score 0):

I do not have MS Access but with other Data Base Systems, I would use SQL to achieve this:

There are several SO answers along these lines for MS Access (try [Microsoft Access - grand total adding multiple fields together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123007/microsoft-access-grand-total-adding-multiple-fields-together))

So start with something like this:

```
Select Name, (A+B+C) as total, A, B, C
  from table1
 order by total desc
```